# How to add a molecule structure to a plot in R using either SMILES or an image?

Tags: r, image, plot

I want to add the molecule structure of 4-aminobenzoic acid to my plot in R. The plot shows the Infrared Spectrum of mentioned molecule. Is there a way to add this using `SMILES` code, which would be `O=C(O)c1ccc(N)cc1` or can I add it as a picture, which can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jf83as9b8p0vrl/aminobenzoic_acid.png?dl=0)(edited in at bottom). I have written following script:

```
par(family="mono", font.axis=1)
data <- read.table("D13-4-aminobenzoic_acid.asc")
x <- data[,1]
y <- data[,2]
x1 <- x[rev(order(x))] # reverse order x

plot(x1,y, type="n", xlim=rev(range(x)),  
     axes=FALSE,
     xlab=expression(paste("Wavelength [", cm^-1,"]")),
     ylab="Transmittance [%]"
     )

lines(x1, y, col="firebrick")

axis(1, at=seq(500,4000,250))
axis(2, at=seq(40,100,10), xpd=T)
```

The .asc file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuuat58q0bf52m8/D13-4-aminobenzoic_acid.asc?dl=0).
I would like the molecule to be positioned at the bottom left, since there is the most space available.

Image shrunk by 85%:

[image]

Comment: Despite that it's for a map, this should work just fine for adding an image to a plot: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4523212/903061. I won't vote to close as duplicate since there might be a solution for the SMILES code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to use the `image()` command in my case. During my research I encountered the command `add.image()`, which seems to be similar to the first mentioned command. However I've never worked with images in R before and know nothing on that matter.

Comment: You can use Open Babel (http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) to convert SMILES to the png format, and add the png file to a plot, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the image file using the `png` and `grid` packages:

```
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("img.png")
grid.raster(img, x=.15, y=.25, width=.3, hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

[image]

Take a look at `?grid.raster` for other arguments of the function. `x` and `y` can be hard to optimize, and note that `width` and `height` are proportions considering the original size.